# How can I get .addOnCompleteListener() methods of Firebase inside a loop?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First of all, let me explain what I'm trying to do.

I have a String date like "2019" and I need to add on database these `n` times the user wants, adding +1 on year each time of the loop.

So, my problems is : I don't know how to get `.addOnCompleteListener()` because it's inside the loop, and I can't treat only one insert. I need to treat all those `n` inserts to give user feedback if all those are successfully inserted.

My example code :

```
//This guarantee same UniqueID for all "n" inserts
final String UniqueID = getDatabaseReference().child("Example").push().getKey();

for (int i = 1 ; i <= n; i++){

    getDatabaseReference()
            .child("Example")
            .child(getFirebaseAuthInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(year)
            .child(UniqueID)
            .setValue(AnyData);

    year =  (Integer.parseInt(year)) + 1) ;
}

listener.success();
```

if it were outside of the loop, I would treat like this :

```
getDatabaseReference()
            .child("Example")
            .child(getFirebaseAuthInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(year)
            .child(UniqueID)
            .setValue(AnyData)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        listener.success();
                    }else {
                        listener.failure();
                    }
                }
            });
```

So, I can't do this method above because the loop will continue, while the insert is not finished, and will give the success for the first one, and the others can fail.

How can I treat inside the loop?
I was thinking about create a `List <Tasks> tasks`, and a `Task task = getfirebase...`, `tasks.add(task)` but I really don't know how to work with it and treat all tasks resulting in success or failure message at OnComplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use recursion. Create a method that will be used to update (try to extract your DB reference outside so that you do not query it every time).
Also you need to know max numer of updates, I guess that would be your 'n'.

```
private static Integer UPDATE_COUNT = 0;
private static final String CHILD = "Example";
private final NotSureAboutType dbReference = getDatabaseReference();
private final SomeType uuid = getFirebaseAuthInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

final String UniqueID = getDatabaseReference().child("Example").push().getKey();

private void updateDB(final NotSureAboutType dbReference,
                      final SomeType uuid,
                      final String uniqueID,
                      final Object anyData,
                      final String year,
                      final Integer n) {
    String tmpYear = year;
    UPDATE_COUNT++;
    dbReference
            .child(CHILD)
            .child(uuid)
            .child(tmpYear)
            .child(UniqueID)
            .setValue(anyData)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        listener.success(); // not sure what this does ?

                        if (UPDATE_COUNT <= n) {
                            updateDB(dbReference, uuid, uniqueID, anyData, (Integer.parseInt(tempyear) + 1), n);
                        }

                    }else {
                        listener.failure();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: the `listener.success()` or `listener.error()` are both methods of the interface implemented, to get the response from the model into the presenter when the ask is done. I'm not sure about your answer but I will try it. I think it possible if I add a stop recursion condition and implement the listener.success() if `UPDATE_COUNT == n`. Appreciate your help.